# iPhone app will push view controller in simulator but not on device

Tags: iphone

I am using a UIButton to call the following IBAction to show a view controller, as far as I am aware this is a normal way of doing this? it works perfectly in the 4.3 simulator but when I run it on a 4.3 iPod the button presses, the code below is called but nothing happens, no error, no feedback, …any ideas?

```
-(void)showAddNewUserView{  
    AddNewUserViewController *AddNewUserView = [[AddNewUserViewController alloc]init];
    [AddNewUserView setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];  
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:AddNewUserView animated:NO];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should it not be -(IBAction)showAddNewUserView?

I'd also consider:

- starting an instance name with a lowercase letter, but that's just me
- sending a [ ... release]; message after pushing the controller

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:AddNewUserView animated:YES];
```

try this one.

Comment: Things I have tried so far are animated:YES and NO, cleaning the build, removing the app from the device and running it again, restarting the device, restarting the MAC.

Comment: purchase a new ipod , purchase a new mac and install fresh xcode on it ... lolzz... sry couldnt stop myself after seing that long effort from u

Comment: It must have something to do with the navigation controller. I am also using this code: -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
} which only works on the simulator again, the nav bar never appears when running on the ipod..